# Can't clone remote git repo from cPanel to local PC

Tags: windows, git, cpanel

I've created GIT repo at my account of shared hosting via cPanel. Then I've installed Git to my local PC with Windows, right-clicked local repo folder and selected the command "Git Bash Here". Next I've run in CMD the command like

```
git clone ssh://user123@example.com/home/user123/public_html/repo
```

First I've received

```
The authenticity of host 'example.com (...)' can't be established.
ED25519 key fingerprint is SHA256:...
This key is not known by any other names
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/[fingerprint])?
```

I've typed "yes" and received the error

```
Warning: Permanently added 'example.com' (ED25519) to the list of known hosts.
user123@example.com: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.
```

Next I've copy-pasted the file id_rsa from the folder `.ssh` at my hosting to my local folder `C:/Users/MyUserName/.ssh`
Now if I run the command of cloning I receive

```
Enter passphrase for key '/c/Users/MyUserName/.ssh/id_rsa':
```

Why? What is the passphrase and where can I get it?

Answer (score 3):

The pass-phrase is the password(s) you used when you created the ssh keys.  You must use those password(s) to unlock access to the ssh keys.

Note that the warnings (about whether the host is known or not) are just that: warnings.  The *first* time you connect to some other system, your ssh software checks the identity message that comes *from* that host.  But there's nothing to check *against*, so you get the warnings.  After that, the identity is saved, so the *second*, *third*, etc., times that you connect to the host, your ssh makes sure it identifies itself the same way.  (This is a fancied-up variant of having the host tell *you* **its** password, which you then check to make sure you're still talking to the same guy.)

Of course, the host doesn't know whether the guy claiming to be you is really you, so the host demands that *you* provide *your* password.  Your "password" in this case is your ssh key ... and your ssh key is protected with *another* password (or rather, "pass phrase": you can use [multiple words](https://xkcd.com/936/)).  So you give *your* machine your "get me the password" pass-phrase, after which your machine gets the password to give to their host.