# git and github desktop not cloning me repository

Tags: git, github, ssh-keys, git-clone, github-desktop

I clone my repository in github desktop but it was showing me this error

[image]

not for only this but for other repo's as well

i sign out/sign in but its still not working

> Note: This is happening after i change my github username and i took a lil break in which i haven't use github at all

After this i create ssh key and download github bash but thats also not working
it showing me this error

[image]

My ssh key was created successfully but i think the error is in repository

i delete and create repo again 2-3 times i also change the repo but didn't work.

any idea what can be the problem here?

Note: In git bash/ github desktop one common error is showing thats
"The folder/directory is not empty" what does it mean? i only have code files in my folder.

Comment: can you try to clone in empty folder??

Comment: Pick one system to use (Git, or GitHub Desktop) and concentrate on getting that working first. For GitHub Desktop, follow its own directions above: use an *empty folder*.

Comment: yes i did @torek

Comment: yes @MuhammadBilalBangash

Answer (score 1):

First, check your key is properly authenticate you!

```
ssh -Tv git@github.com
```

You should see a welcome message like:

```
Hi Me! 
You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
```

(`Me` being your GitHub user account)

Second, clone your repository in command line:

```
git clone git@github.com:me/myRepo
```

That will create a subfolder `myRepo`.

Comment: @Saman That is expected on GitHub side. But what `ssh -Tv git@github.com` says from your own computer?

Comment: hey  @VonC                                                                                                                          1)about ssh key it says i have generated ssh key on my github account but it doesn't say my name or anything just key name.                                                                         2)   and do i need to install github.CLI to clone repo in command line?

Comment: @Saman Whenever a tool/IDE does not work as expected, installing the CLI is always a good idea: you will get more clues that way.

Comment: it says the key is associated with my github account and thats it

Comment: @Saman Can you edit your question with the exact output of `ssh -Tv git@github.com`?

Comment: i edited my question u can see it now + i install n clone my repo in cli as well everything goes well and it seems to work but the live url its still the same. Also in github desktop before last time when i clone repo it was showing all well but the result in github url isn't showing.

Comment: @Saman is your private key passphrase-protected? (as [discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69712924/6309)). Also, of interest: https://github.com/desktop/desktop/issues/13050

Comment: uhh no its not i think now i should delete it bcz it wasn't safe to show it like this.

Comment: @Saman Agreed. Once you make it work, regenerate and register a new set of keys.

Comment: can u plz help me with fixing it on github desktop?   I have tried to solve it with multiple ways everything is very new to me now so i have difficulty in doing it with other source like cli/gitbash  So now i want to stick with one thing i know something about

Comment: @Saman I would recommend making it work from command line first (`git clone git@github.com:me/myRepo`). Once that is working from CLI, you can switch to GitHub Desktop and check it works there.